# How to acces a global variable in a callback object in javascript YUI without use window.myvariable?

Tags: javascript, yui

I have this :

```
var MyObject = function(){   
   this.url = "monurl";   
   this.mavar = "";   
   this.Load = function(){
     var callback = {
       success: function(o){
         mavar = o.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("montag")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
       }
     }
     YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('GET',url,callback);
} }
```

the mavar variable is not accessible. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can set a scope param to the callback. So you should be able to do something like the following.

```
var MyObject = function(){   
   this.url = "monurl";   
   this.mavar = "";   
   this.Load = function(){
     var callback = {
       success: function(o){
         this.mavar = o.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("montag")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
       },
       scope: this
     }
     YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('GET', this.url, callback);
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the `this` variable:

```
var MyObject = function() {   
   this.url = "monurl";   
   this.mavar = "";   
   this.Load = function() {
     var me = this;
     var callback = {
       success: function(o) {
         me.mavar = o.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("montag")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
       }
     }
     YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('GET',url,callback);
  }
}
```

Comment: The second approach (accessing it via the object name) isn't going to work. You're adding a property `mavar` to the constructor function object—not the actual `MyObject` object *instance*. The first way, saving `this` to another variable (I like to call it `_this` or `self`), is the best way to go.

Comment: @Steve: Right, edited. Didn't notice that it was a constructor rather than an object literal.

Comment: Right! I try it and my choice is to put the this to another variable.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it like this:

```
var MyObject = new function(){   
   this.url = "monurl";   
   this.mavar = "";   
   this.Load = 
   (function(that){ 
        return function(){
            var callback = {
                success: function(o){
                    that.mavar = o.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("montag")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                }
            }
            YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('GET',url,callback);
        } 
    })(this);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my object, I add a variable that's reference the this :

```
var selfMyObject = this;
```

and I replace the this.mavar to selfMyObject.mavar in success callback and it's work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to let YUI do your scope correction, since support is built in. Here's the docs page telling you how to to do it. http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/connection/#scope

```
var MyObject = function() {
    this.url = "monurl";
    this.mavar = "";
    this.Load = function() {
        var callback = {
            success: function(o){
                this.mavar = o.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("montag")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            },
            scope: this
        }

        YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('GET', url, callback);
    }
}
```